# discord.py change nickname after a modal submit

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, discord-interactions

I wanted to change my modal a nickname but unfortunately do not know exactly how

this is my code

```
class RenameModal(ui.Modal, title="Rename"):
  vorname = ui.TextInput(label="Vorname", placeholder="Mein Vorname lautet...", required=True, style=discord.TextStyle.short)
  nachname = ui.TextInput(label="Nachname", placeholder="Mein Nachname lautet...", required=True, style=discord.TextStyle.short)
  spielerid = ui.TextInput(label="ID", placeholder="Meine ID lautet...", required=True, style=discord.TextStyle.short)

  async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
    await interaction.user.edit(nick=f'{self.vorname} {self.nachname} | {self.spielerid}')

@client.tree.command(name="rename", description="rename")
async def rename(interaction: discord.Interaction):
  await interaction.response.send_modal(RenameModal())
```

as mentioned before i would like to change the nickname of the user after sending the modal

so far I have only tried that and found nothing about it

```
await interaction.user.edit(nick=f'{self.vorname} {self.nachname} | {self.spielerid}')
```

Comment: that‘s the correct code

Comment: Hey @Kejax thank you for your reply,

when i write this line it says:
`Cannot access member "edit" for type "User"`

When i execute the command in a normal discord channel it says:
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lepla\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ui\modal.py", line 186, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
TypeError: RenameModal.on_submit() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'
```

The bot has adminestrator permissions

Comment: Im sorry but it seems like the code you sent in the question isn’t the one you‘re using right now.

Comment: @Kejax Hey ive got sill the same code.

Comment: @Icxless there's a different between `User` and `Member`, `User` is the global interpretation and `Member` is guild-based, you can only edit `Member` nicknames, not `User`

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński Hey thank you for your reply. Do you know how i can change a nickname on a server with that modal?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński The object that is being returned is depending on where the modal is used. Is it used in a guild, then a member object is being returned

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
await interaction.user.edit
```

to

```
await interaction.member.edit
```

as `user` is the global term that is used for all over Discord, and `member` is the term used for a user in a specific Guild.